# Data Races in Sequential Code

Tags: concurrency, race-condition, sequential

Are data races prevalent in sequential code? If so is it the job of a programmer to worry about these types of data races?

I had the question posed to me in the way that it seemed that data races were in fact prevalent in sequential code however I have not come across any information that discusses data races outside of concurrency. When do data races occur in sequential code? And are these instances of data races significant enough to have a programmer handle them?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't multiple things to race in sequential code.

At least, not unless you're interacting with something external e.g. I/O, network, disk, etc.  For example, you might do something like this (pseudocode):

```
if (directory_exists(dir_name)) {
    cd(dir_name);
}
```

But of course, some external entity might have deleted the directory in between the two API calls.